# Javascript lives system broken in web design

Tags: javascript, html

so I'm coding a quiz on HTML as a competition with my friend, and I'm making a lives system but it seems to do skip the fact that there are lives 2 and 3 and do what it would do if you lost a life when you had 1 life.

JavaScript:

```js
var lives = 3;
var loadLives = setInterval(showLives, 100);

function loseLife() {
    if (lives = 1) {
        location.href='fail.html';
        lives = 3;
    }
    else {
        lives = lives - 1;  
    }
}

function showLives() {
    document.getElementById("lifeamount").innerHTML = lives;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<a class="wa" href="javascript:loseLife()">Here?</a>
```

I do have more HTML but that's the line that executes the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
if (lives = 1) {
```

Right now, it's not comparing lives to 1, but it's assigning 1 to lives. You'd need something like this instead:

```
if (lives === 1) {
```

Comment: id found out my solution to problem just before this showed up i think but thx anyways at least now from your answer i understand what the problem was :D

Answer (score 1):

dont worry i somehow found a solution :D

```
var lives = 3;
var loadLives = setInterval(showLives, 100);

function loseLife() {
    if (lives > 1) {
        lives = --lives;
    }
    else {
        location.href='fail.html';
    }
}

function showLives() {
    document.getElementById("lifeamount").innerHTML = lives;
}
```

and same html

Comment: Small nitpick: `lives = --lives;` is sub-optimal: You could write instead `lives -= 1` or `lives--` or `--lives`, but as it is, it performs a redundant assignment.